# webservice call returns 403 Access Denied on an external sharepoint server 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I am getting the **"Request failed with HTTP status 403:Access Denied"** error on calling any SharePoint web-service on a SharePoint server 2010. This is an external server and not in my VPN. This server belongs to a client so I have no clue about the authentication. The client has given full control to me on the webapplication.

The strange thing is that even if I do not provide any username or password I am getting the same 403 error while I should be getting 401 error in the absence of username/password.

This mean there is something wrong with the given server configuration that even without varying the user identity 403 is getting returned.

Any clue about what could be wrong at the SharePoint server configuration or web-application configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They may have Claims Authentication with either multiple authentication or Trusted Identity Provider configured. Open Fiddler on your client and do the log in process. Look for the "FedAuth" cookie once successfully authenticated. Or look for other clues in Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for reply Steven. In the Fiddler for the server where the problem is I am not seeing any cookie. But on another sharepoint server(Which is working) I can see following cookies in header Proxy-Support:Session-Based-Authentication WWW-Authenticate:NTLM. So it seems that there something related to NTLM authentication not sure though.

Comment: Are you using a proxy server on your LAN? Could you try your code on a network that doesn't use a proxy server?